# HTML Url encoding causes error opening file

Tags: html, ms-office, url-scheme, onenote

I have a intranet application which serves the user a link to OneNote notebook.

The link to file is created like this:

```
onenote:\\\\public\Projects\17225 Some špečial characters\17225.one
```

Note the special characters. When I hover over the button with that href, on both Chrome and IE it shows the correct URI. When I click on it in IE, the OneNote opens the correct notebook.

But when I try to open it with Chrome, it throws an error saying:

> "We couldn't open that location. It might not exist or you might not
>   have permission to open it. Please contact the owner of "*onenote:\\public\Projects\17225 Some **%C5%BDpe%C4%8Dial** characters\17225.one*" for more information."

Here we see that the URI changed.

How to avoid that without omitting the special characters? Why does the buggy old IE works as expected?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on opening url with chrome.

I can fix setting default program to OneNote marketplace app.

Windows 10, Settings > App > Default apps > Set Default By Programs
(link: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-set-default-programs-in-windows-10/)

[image]